D-Bus timeout: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
I'm running some test ovirt environment. I have 3 hosts in a cluster/datacenter, about 90 vms on them. For the means of testing I have been adding multiple VLAN's to hosts (about 300 at this point). And I'm having trouble with firewalld - its stopped reacting to any firewall-cmd commands. While NFT is working, yet it takes about 2+ minutes to print all rules. What I get is an error from dbus, it timed out waiting for reply.
I have tried adding .conf file in dbus's system.d folder (/etc/dbus-1/system.d), like on screenshot:
[1]
But that produced no effect, timeout is still 25 seconds. I am reading dbus daemon manual, but I can't understand how to make a correct change to a specific firewalld service. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Question: is it possible to change default 25 second timeout for dbus? Specifically for firewalld, preferably.

Just how many rules do you have that nftables takes two minutes to print them?

Many, and it seems all of them are faulty. I get a lot of netfilter in system logs. Like its trying to write rules all the time.
